# Filtered by token holder?

Tags: tokens, access

I swapped Ethereum for Synaps through Pancake. The transaction shows up as valid but i can't transfer/receive my Synaps to/in my external wallet,

There is a message in bold that says: **Filtered by token holder**. Can that be the problem?
If so, what can i do to get access and being able to transfer them?

Tnx.

Comment: What wallet are you using? What's the account address? What's the transaction hash?

Comment: Wallet: Nano s and/or Metamask.

Comment: Account address: 0x0d9F06FaF803fDEE0752733Ab765dDfE17971AB1

Comment: Transaction hash: 0x7b6a1cc2bc05cb18863056c023c7ae1f613a753d88890df7ab04e7c77987f403

Comment: The token was transferred correctly, the contract seems legit. You should be able to transfer the token, but you need some ether to pay the transaction fee.

Comment: Tnx for clarifying that.
I bought some other Ecr-20 token earlier (shiba) and reveived it on my Nano through ledger live. Synapse (although also Ecr-20) is not a supporred token on ledger live and it didn't arrive.

So maybe you can help me find a way to transfer my Synapse.  Where are they now and how to approach them to transfer?

Do I have to write a new contract on Etherscan to do so?

Tnx again.

Pjot

Comment: The tokens are at `0x0d9F06FaF803fDEE0752733Ab765dDfE17971AB1`, together with some SHIB tokens, you could see them on etherscan. You could use some other wallet that supports your ledger and custom tokens, MyEtherWallet and MyCrypto used to support both.